# How to flip LTspice voltage controlled switch so that it opens at threshold voltage? (versus close)

Tags: switches, ltspice

I am trying to figure out how to tell the VSWITCH of the LTspice program to open after it crosses the threshold voltage and close when it is below (with hysteresis). Normal behavior is that with Vt and Vh defined, it'll close when the voltage is greater than (Vt + Vh) and open when the voltage is lower (Vt - Vh).

Unfortunately I can't use another component or edit my schematic since I am working off of a .lib file for an IC, and am attempting to edit the text commands so I can import it into MATLAB for Simscape simulations with physical components (torque, etc.). Basically, I want to ensure that my IC behavior is correct once I import it.

Comment: Another thing you can do is use a voltage controlled resistor with something like `R={If(X>Y,1,1e9)}`

Comment: swap the terminals and set the threshold negative

Comment: Any reason you can't just make Ron high and Roff low?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the LTSpice help file:

> Symbol Names: SW
>
> Syntax: Sxxx n1 n2 nc+ nc-  [on,off]
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> S1 out 0 in 0 MySwitch
> .model MySwitch SW(Ron=.1 Roff=1Meg Vt=0 Vh=-.5 Lser=10n Vser=.6)
> ```
>
> The voltage between nodes nc+ and nc- controls the switch's impedance between nodes n1 and n2. A model card is required to define the behavior of the switch.

So if you switch the connections to the `nc+` and `nc-` pins and invert (multiply by -1) the `Vt` value, you should get the effect you want.

Answer (score 1):

make Ron=1Meg, Roff=1p, it will work visaversa